# Covered index doesn't appear to be optimal. Expecting 0 heap fetches in execution plan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm using the pagilia sample database on Postgres 14. I create what I think is the covered index, followed by the query, based on an example for an online course...

```
CREATE INDEX idx_film_cover ON film (rating, length, title, replacement_cost, rental_rate);

EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT title, length, rating, replacement_cost, rental_rate
FROM film
WHERE length BETWEEN 60 AND 70 AND rating = 'G';
```

...yet I still get a bitmap heap scan...

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on film as film
Recheck Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan using idx_film_cover
      Index Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))
```

...the online course example has zero heaps. Can someone help me understand why I'm getting a different execution plan?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't `VACUUM` the table.

Comment: Please show us the **complete** execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: You perhaps know you should not have any, Postgres does not **know that**. It must generate then execute the plan to discover it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name '''Bitmap Heap Scan on film  (cost=4.47..39.34 rows=15 width=34) (actual time=0.473..1.202 rows=18 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))
  Heap Blocks: exact=14
  Buffers: shared hit=17 read=2
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_film_cover  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=0.264..0.264 rows=18 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))
        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2
Planning Time: 0.188 ms
Execution Time: 1.244 ms'''